# Problem with built matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have function which set relation between distance and some coefficient. I have build usual plot - there is no problem and I get my coefficien equal max 1. See please code and plot for it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})

x = np.linspace(0, 8, 800)

f1 = 3 * (x/8)**4 - 8 * (x/8)**3 + 6 * (x/8)**2

plt.plot(x, f1, ':b', label='1st component')

plt.xlabel(r'$x$', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(r'$f(x)$', fontsize=16)

plt.xlim([0, 8])
plt.ylim([0, 1.1])

plt.legend(fontsize=14)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

And now I need apply this function for surface for every azimut direction. For this I would like use contour plot.

First of all, as this coefficient dont changing for every azimut I expect that it wil be same i.e. circle, second - my function should give me coefficient max 1. But I get strange plot and k max = 1.44.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

xx = np.linspace(-8, 8, 100)
yy = np.linspace(-8, 8, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
        
        
ZX = 3 * (abs(X)/8)**4 - 8 * (abs(X)/8)**3 + 6 * (abs(X)/8)**2
ZY = 3 * (abs(Y)/8)**4 - 8 * (abs(Y)/8)**3 + 6 * (abs(Y)/8)**2
Z = np.sqrt(np.square(ZX) + np.square(ZY))

cs = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='rainbow')
plt.clabel(cs)
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(which='major')
plt.title('Contours Plot')
plt.xlabel('X (m)')
plt.ylabel('Y (k)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Description]

Could you please explain how I can apply my function for the surface via matplotlib contour that get circle and max coef = 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the contours, you can pass a list to the `levels` `kwarg` in `contour`. The list will specify which levels to plot (if you pass a scalar then it will plot that many levels over the entire range). So, if you only want levels between 0 and 1 and you want 10 levels, you can set `levels=np.linspace(0, 1, 10)`. In the `contour` call, that would look like this:

```py
min_level = 0
max_level = 1
n_levels = 10
levels = np.linspace(min_level, max_level, n_levels)
cs = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, cmap='rainbow', levels=levels)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But this is not what I need actually... How I can concatenate three different function with conditions like "if-elif-else" on different levels (x < 8, 8 < x < 64, x > 64) on one contour plot?

Comment: Can you provide more reasonable numbers for this specific example?

Comment: For now I can see that can get it only by plotting three different plot for every condition... 'if np.any(X <= 8):
    r = np.sqrt(np.square(X) + np.square(Y))
    Z = 3 * (r/8)**4 - 8 * (r/8)**3 + 6 * (r/8)**2
    np.place(Z, r > 8, np.nan)
if np.any(X <= 64):
    r = np.sqrt(np.square(X) + np.square(Y))
    Z1 = 1.13 / (0.13 * (r / 8)**2 +1)
    np.place(Z1, r < 8, np.nan)
    np.place(Z1, r > 64, np.nan)
    
cs = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='rainbow')
cs = plt.contour(X, Y, Z1, 20, cmap='rainbow')'

Comment: Number dont mean anything, lets change it to 'n'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply your function to the distance from (0, 0), rather than individually to `X` and `Y`.  If you want to not plot the function where that distance is greater than 8, you can insert `np.nan` in those places (or [apply a mask](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html) if you prefer).

```
r = np.sqrt(np.square(X) + np.square(Y))
Z = 3 * (r/8)**4 - 8 * (r/8)**3 + 6 * (r/8)**2
np.place(Z, r > 8, np.nan)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that what I need exactly! Regarding to plot with distance greater than 8 - in this case I need to apply another function. So, question is how can I use condition (for instance "if") in matplotlib context?